# How to remove the closed topic of exact duplicate

Tags: bug, closed-questions, duplicates

Hi its my thread I started
[Photoshop Installation in 10.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231512/photoshop-installation-in-10-10)

Actually i asking the question for the version of ubuntu 10.10 but someone's are closed my topic is exactly duplicate.

How to inform him about my thread is deals the version 10.10 of ubuntu ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version specific tag *10.10* is used to denote that a question has a hardware specific connotation - it is rarely used for software issues.

On Ask Ubuntu, we gather together similar questions under one canonical question.  This makes it easier to search and also maintain the answers.

This is what has happened in this case.  Your question is a direct duplicate with answers that are relevant to your situation - in this case, installing wine and then installing photoshop.

How you install an up-to-date wine package on 10.10 to allow you to install photoshop is actually a different question - you are most welcome to pose that if required.

Note - EOL questions are *on-topic* here on Ask Ubuntu - but you will often get comments urging you to consider upgrading since most (but not all) have done so to ensure they have the latest supported configuration.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for your Information ...